# How to reload multiple pjax

Tags: yii2, pjax

i just want to know how to reload multiple pjax? this is my code

```
        $.pjax.reload({container:"#con_camp"});
        $.pjax.reload({container:"#con_camp1"});
```

but only the #con_camp1 is the one that will reload.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this.

```
   $.pjax.reload({container: "#1-pjax", async:false});
    $.pjax.reload({container: "#2-pjax", async:false});
```

Comment: i vote for this. i use yii framework and the problem is the widget i use. but when i use other widgets, this code works.

Comment: Yea this works @GAMITG but if server takes time to process any of those ajax requests then your browser literally hangs untill it receives the response from server. Any workaround for that?

Answer (score 8):

You could just do

```
$.pjax.reload({container: '#container_1'}).done(function () {
    $.pjax.reload({container: '#container_2'});
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately Pjax by design doesn't allow multiple requests. In order to do those you have to nullify `xhr` parameter in `$.pjax`.

Basically like this:

```
$.pjax.reload({container:"#con_camp"});
$.pjax.xhr = null;
$.pjax.reload({container:"#con_camp1"});
$.pjax.xhr = null; // so that some next pjax request wont cancel this reload.
```

Comment: This "works" but then responses can come out of order. For example if pjax request A takes 10 seconds and pjax request B takes 2 seconds, response A will come in after response B, even though B was the last request made by the user. This is confusing and incorrect behavior.

Comment: Alex, setting the xhr to null as you showed worked for a similar issue I am having. Could you help me understand in simple  terms why it gets "canceled"?

Answer (score 2):

When using `async:false` both Chrome and Firefox are throwing this:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

A different way to do it is to use the [pjax:end](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events) event that will trigger when a container is completely reloaded to register the code that will reload the next one. That way they'll get reloaded one by one:

```
var pjaxContainers = ['#pjax-block-1', '#pjax-block-2', '#pjax-block-3'];

$.each(pjaxContainers , function(index, container) { 
     if (index+1 < pjaxContainers.length) {
          $(container).one('pjax:end', function (xhr, options) {
               $.pjax.reload({container: pjaxContainers[index+1]}) ;
          });
     }
});

$.pjax.reload({container: pjaxContainers[0]}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue , I have done in this way.

```
 <?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'pjax_id']); ?>

 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>

// Under SCRIPT tag
    $.pjax.reload({container: '#pjax_id', async: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to add to the  `$.pjax.xhr=null` solution, since this by itself has a bug- it will allow an earlier, but longer-running request to load the response data into the target container after a subsequent, faster running request. This would obviously be unexpected behavior. The user expects the latest click to be the one that loads the response into the container.

The solution is to add a reference to the previous xhr object somewhere it can be accessed on the next pjax event. I use the window namespace

```
$('.pjax-container').on('pjax:send', function(event, xhr, options) {
    // unique data attribute of the pjax container
    xhrName=$(this).attr('data-myXhrName');
    // abort pending requests because we are allowing multiples
    if (window.xhrRef[xhrName]) {
        window.xhrRef[xhrName].abort();
    }
    $.pjax.xhr=null;

    window.xhrRef[xhrName]=xhr;
})
.on('pjax:complete', function(event, xhr, options) {    
        xhrName=$(this).attr('data-myXhrName');
        // we're done with it
        window.xhrRef[xhrName]=false;
})
```